# How do you use the present perfect after "since"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

My understanding is that "since" indicates the start of an event, so it's understandable to use the past simple after "since", as in

- "It's been ten years since we **met** each other."

However, I sometimes see the present perfect used in a "since" clause instead of the past simple.

- "It's been ten years since we **have met** each other."

The present perfect usually convey a different meaning from the past simple (you'd never say "I have met him ten years ago", would you?), but here they seem to be the same.  Is there any difference between "since we met" and "since we have met" here?  If not, does that mean you can use the present perfect instead of the past simple in a "since" clause?  For example,

- I've been playing basketball since I **have entered** this school.

I would say "since I entered this school," but is it also correct to say "since I have entered this school"?

Comment: No, it isn't. In some circumstances you could use the present perfect continuous - _I've been playing basketball since I've been coming to this school - I've done my shopping at Brown's Supermarket ever since I've been living here_.

Comment: What makes the difference?

Comment: Just that we use the simple past tense with _since (a date or event)._ Note that in my examples it would be more usual to say _since I started at/entered this school_ and _since I moved here_, but the versions with the continuous tense are possible.